# Can anyone please breakdown this schema code?

Tags: javascript, schema

I was searching for some random keywords on google and one thing stunt me the search result looks very organized. While digging into deep I found that they are using Schema but I didn't understand any bit of it from their website schema.org/docs/full.html

**Here is the search result:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eq0fT.png

**And here is the code:**

```js
{
 "@context": "http://schema.org",
 "@type": "WebPage"
 ,"breadcrumb": {
"@type": "BreadcrumbList",
"itemListElement": [
{
"@type": "ListItem",
"position": 1,
"item": {
"@id": "https://www.thespruce.com/home-design-and-decorating-4127998",
"name": "Home Decor"
}
}
,
{
"@type": "ListItem",
"position": 2,
"item": {
"@id": "https://www.thespruce.com/best-home-products-4135328",
"name": "Best Home Products"
}
}
]
}  
,"mainEntity": {
"@type": "Article",
"mainEntityOfPage": {
"@type": "Webpage",
"@id": "https://www.thespruce.com/best-washer-dryer-sets-4109183"
},
"headline": "The 8 Best Washer &amp;amp; Dryer Sets of 2019"
,"datePublished": "2016-12-15T17:48:12.000Z"
,"dateModified": "2019-02-28T02:54:03.871Z"
,"author": {
"@type": "Person",
"name": "Erica Puisis"
}
,"description": "Shop for the best washer and dryer combos on the market today from brands like Whirlpool, LG, and GE."
,"image": [
{
"@type": "ImageObject",
"url": "https://www.thespruce.com/thmb/mOZ7phvcHDbkVlyMgMEzOSrmFZ0=/1500x844/smart/filters:no_upscale()/Laundry-room-organization-56a4a89c5f9b58b7d0d8209b.jpg",
"height": 844,
"width": 1500
},
{
"@type": "ImageObject",
"url": "https://www.thespruce.com/thmb/tbpSTix7BOux_5DQ7KOFVnOvKUY=/1333x1000/smart/filters:no_upscale()/Laundry-room-organization-56a4a89c5f9b58b7d0d8209b.jpg",
"height": 1000,
"width": 1333
},
{
"@type": "ImageObject",
"url": "https://www.thespruce.com/thmb/o_dkwQfWerJ6y96wbb6nCpVdoYA=/1000x1000/smart/filters:no_upscale()/Laundry-room-organization-56a4a89c5f9b58b7d0d8209b.jpg",
"height": 1000,
"width": 1000
}
]
,"publisher": {
"@type": "Organization",
"name": "The Spruce",
"logo": {
"@type": "ImageObject",
"url": "https://www.thespruce.com/thmb/8kMPEcNCetsLR0R15xvnVcMOZ3c=/139x60/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/TheSpruce-Logo-amp60H-59b00f31d963ac0011c633b9.png",
"width": 139,
"height": 60
},
"brand": "The Spruce"
, "publishingPrinciples": "https://www.thespruce.com/about-us#editorial-guidelines"
}
,"mainEntity": {
"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "ItemList",
"name": "The 8 Best Washer &amp;amp; Dryer Sets of 2019",
"description": "Shop for the best washer and dryer combos on the market today from brands like Whirlpool, LG, and GE.",
"itemListOrder": "http://schema.org/ItemListUnordered",
"numberOfItems": 8,
"itemListElement": [
{
"@type": "ListItem",
"position": 1
,"name": "Best Overall: Samsung WF45M5500AP Washer and DVE45M5500P Dryer with Steam"
},
{
"@type": "ListItem",
"position": 2
,"name": "Best Smart Top-Loading: GE 5.0 cu. ft. Washer and 7.4 cu. ft. Smart Dryer"
},
{
"@type": "ListItem",
"position": 3
,"name": "Best High-End: Bosch 800 Series White Front Load Compact Laundry Stacked Pair"
},
{
"@type": "ListItem",
"position": 4
,"name": "Best Energy Efficient: Whirlpool WTW4816FW Washer and WED4815EW Dryer"
},
{
"@type": "ListItem",
"position": 5
,"name": "Best Smart Front-Loading: LG 5.2 cu. ft. Washer with Steam and 9.0 cu. ft. Dryer"
},
{
"@type": "ListItem",
"position": 6
,"name": "Best High-Capacity: Kenmore Elite Front Load Washer and Dryer Bundle"
},
{
"@type": "ListItem",
"position": 7
,"name": "Best Budget: Amana 3.5 CU.&amp;#39; Top Loading Washing Machine"
},
{
"@type": "ListItem",
"position": 8
,"name": "Best for Small Spaces: GE Washer and Electric Dryer Laundry Center"
}
]
}
}  
}
```

**Can anyone please breakdown this schema code? I am sure they are using a lot of schema but I want to know section by section. Which section use for what!**

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What have you tried so far yourself?

Comment: I want to know where each code started and ends

Comment: But **show us** how you have tried to do this so far. SO isn't a code-writing service, you need to have made a start yourself.